# How to capture output and send it to file

Tags: go

I have a program that does some processing and I'd like to give the option to save the output to a file, however, I am not able to find the best way to do this.

```
if (strings.ToLower(input2) == "y") || (strings.ToLower(input2) == "yes") {
    fmt.Println("\nOutputting to file, please wait... ")
    oldSt := os.Stdout //Create backup of old Stdout
    newFil, _ := os.Create(input+"txt")

    os.Stdout = newFil
    table.Render()

    os.Stdout = oldSt
    fmt.Println("\nComplete!")
}
```

This is my current code, but it seems it is just printing to the console without redirecting to the file.

I am using this package to create a table which is what I am trying to output to the file.

https://github.com/olekukonko/tablewriter

Is there a better way of outputting to the file or because I am calling a library function would it be a different method of writing?

Answer (score 2):

Why are you changing `os.Stdout` to a file for your library? It seems as though the tablewriter package you're using accepts the `io.Writer` you'd like it to use:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"

    "github.com/olekukonko/tablewriter"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Outputting to file, please wait...")
    f, err := os.Create("mahfile.txt")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer f.Close()

    table := tablewriter.NewWriter(f)
    table.Render()
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/4L5Qu2SA4Uy

Obviously you may need to declare things in a different order, but I wouldn't recommend changing the expected functionality of `os.Stdout` to accomplish your goal. They're just using it as a placeholder for you to overwrite.

---

However, to answer your question: When you initialized `tablewriter.NewWriter(os.Stdout)`, you provided it with a copy to the `io.Writer` of STDOUT - Replacing `os.Stdout` later in your application does not undo this.

To accomplish what you're wanting, you will need to provide a different writer that can be aware of this change as it potentially occurs, if this is needed (see first answer)

Comment: And if OP wants to output to both the file and stdout then he can use an `io.MultiWriter`.

Comment: Great point @AKstat - To add to that, you can also leverage a `bytes.Buffer` to temporarily buffer the output and then redirect it to an additional `io.Writer`, allowing you to cancel redirection at a later time without much complexity.

Answer (score 1):

Since `tablewriter.NewWriter` takes the output file as an argument

```
tablewriter.NewWriter(os.Stdout)
```

And `os.Stdout` itself is just a `*File`, you can just pass a different file to the NewWriter.

```
var outputFile = os.Stdout

if userWantsToOutputToFile {
    var userFile, fileErr = os.Create(desiredOutputFilename)
    if fileErr != nil {
        outputFile = userFile
    }
}

// do your initialization

// then
tablewriter.NewWriter(outputFile)
```

As an aside, (just an FYI) If you are running your own process, you can just redirect the output to a file on the shell

```
$ your_program -some-flags > output.txt
```